# $GEM_HOME and $GEM_PATH are wrongly set in Passenger

Tags: ruby, nginx, docker, rubygems, passenger

I am trying to setup a rails(v4.2.6) application using Passenger(v5.1.4)+Nginx in a docker container. 
I used official ruby 2.3.1 as base image.

Following is my nginx file for site

```
server {
  server_name example.local;

  listen 4000;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  root /www/app/public;

  passenger_ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby;

  try_files $uri @passenger;

  location @passenger {
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env development;
  }

  ...
}
passenger_pre_start http://0.0.0.0:4000/status;
```

More context:

- Ruby binary is present at `/usr/local/bin/ruby`
- Gems are installed in `/usr/local/bundle`

But when I start nginx service, I get following error

```
It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run:

bundle install
If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following:
```

passenger is not able to find app gems because, GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH are set wrongly

[image: Taken from passenger error page]

I have tried to set environment variable `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` manually in docker-entrypoint to correct gem path, i.e `/usr/local/bundle`. However its not working.

How can I make passenger to use correct gemset.

**Note:** I am not using `rvm`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for this issue was [user_sandboxing by passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/user_sandboxing.html)

Since my app directory was owned by root, and I had no `passenger_default_user` configured in nginx, passenger was staring application as user `nobody` and group `nogroup`

I fixed this issue by changing owner of my app directory to a non-root user.

Note: Also I had to go with rvm instead of ruby:2.3.1 base image.